# Loop property of TidThreadComponent

Tags: multithreading, delphi, indy

I have a (hopefully) simple question:

What is the meaning of `Loop` property of `TidThreadComponent`?

My program with threads works well when compiled in Delphi 7, but threads works unpredictable when compiled under Delphi Embarcadero. I suspect  `Loop` property of `TidThreadComponent` (don't remember it in Delphi 7).

The name `Loop` says that `Loop=true`  should make he thread to start in the loop until terminated manually. However, something else is observed.

Thanks in advance for any idea.

Comment: What is "Delphi Embarcadero"? Embarcadero is the name of the company that owns Delphi these days, it is not the name of a Delphi version. It would be helpful if you added the actual version of Delphi you are using (such as Delphi 2009, or Delphi XE7, or Delphi 10.3, or ...).

Comment: It would also help if (in addition to the actual Delphi version) you indicated the version of Indy that you're using.

Comment: The source code for `TIdThread` shows the use of `Loop`. If it's True (the default) then the code executes a `while not Stopped do` loop that calls `Run` repeatedly. As you've not provided code, it's impossible to tell you why *something else is observed*.

Comment: Thanks to everybody who answer. Version of IDE is Embarcadero® Delphi 10.3 Version 26.0.33219.4899. I don't involve Indy (at least, explicitly). I could provide the code, but it is more than hundred lines, and there is a problem to make a little example (each of the line might be essential for the question).
When `loop` is `true`, indeed `run` method repeats (`before` and `after` perform once). However, when `loop` is `false`, all these three methods repeat until being terminated.

Comment: Your code does explicitly involve Indy, because `TIdThreadComponent` is an Indy component, which wraps `TIdThread`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation of `TIdThread`, which `TIdThreadComponent` wraps:

> Loop is a Boolean property used to indicate if the Run method for the thread instance is called in a loop.
>
> When Loop contains True (the default value assigned in Create), the Run method will be continuously executed until Stopped returns True.
>
> When Loop contains False, the Run method is called once during execution of the thread.

You ask if `Loop=true` should make the thread "start in the loop until terminated manually", but it is more accurate to say that the thread's `Run()` method is looped until the thread is *stopped*, not *terminated*.  Two different concepts in Indy.  A thread can be *stopped* without being *terminated*, this allows the thread to be restarted.  For instance, when using `TIdSchedulerOfThreadPool`.

When a `TIdThread` is *stopped*, it stops calling its `Run()` method and will then either `Terminate()` or `Suspend()` itself, depending on its `StopMode` property.  The default is `smTerminate`.

`TIdThreadComponent` runs an internal `TIdThread/Ex`, which is derived from `TThread`.  And like most uses of Delphi threads, the thread's `Execute()` method runs a `while not Terminated` loop.  Inside that `Terminated` loop, the thread's `Loop` property controls whether the thread's `Run()` method is called once per loop iteration, or is called in its own `while not Stopped` loop per iteration.  In other words, it is the difference between this:

```
while not Terminated do
begin
  if Stopped then
  begin
    if Terminated then Break;
    Suspend;
    if Terminated then Break;
  end;
  BeforeRun;
  Run; // <-- Loop=false
  AfterRun;
end;
```

And this:

```
while not Terminated do
begin
  if Stopped then
  begin
    if Terminated then Break;
    Suspend;
    if Terminated then Break;
  end;
  BeforeRun;
  while not Stopped do Run; // <-- Loop=true
  AfterRun;
end;
```

So, what it basically just boils down to is that `Loop` controls how many times `Run()` is called in between `BeforeRun()` and `AfterRun()`, nothing more.  The thread will keep calling `Run()` nonetheless until the thread is either *stopped* or *terminated*.